# Auto-select page orientation for tables

Tags: tables, landscape, booktabs, python

I am trying to write a python script that takes a matrix and converts it to a latex document containing just one table. I have most things sorted out, and I can get e.g. a table TeX file outputted like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\begin{table}[htp]
\begin{center}
\label{tab:w2}
\begin{tabular}{cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc}
\toprule
                {a} & {b}\\
                \midrule
                $1$ & $2$ & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-}\\
                $3$ & $4$ & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-}\\
                $5$ & $6$ & $7$ & $8$ & $9$ & $9$ & $9$ & $9$ & $9$ & $9$ & $9$ & $9$ & $9$ & $9$ & $9$ & $9$ & $9$ & $9$ & $9$ & $9$ & $9$ & $9$ & $9$ & $9$ & $9$ & $9$ & $9$ & $9$ & $9$ & $9$ & $9$ & $9$ & $9$ & $9$ & $9$ & $9$\\             
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

I would like my table to be typeset in either landscape or portrait orientation depending on its aspect ratio (in the example above it should be portrait). This is difficult to do on the python side, since python does not know what font, spacing, etc LaTeX will use. is there any way to specify such a content-dependent page orientation via the LaTeX code?

Comment: what about `standalone` class?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution. We use a savebox measuring it's width here I test if it is larger then `\textwidth` you can replace it by any value. If you use `Koma-script` class you  change orientation is very easy.

**Updated** textwidth adjusted. We try

```
\addtolength{\textwidth}{-2\oddsidemargin}%
\addtolength{\textwidth}{-2\hoffset}%
\addtolength{\textwidth}{-2in}%
```

to make text centered

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
 a4paper,
 total={210mm,297mm},
 left=15mm,
 right=15mm,
 top=15mm,
 bottom=15mm,
 }
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newsavebox\mt
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\begin{document}
\sbox\mt{%
        \begin{tabular}{cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc}
        \toprule
            a & b & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-}\\
            1 & 2 & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-} & {-}\\
            3 & 4 & $1$ & $2$ & $3$ & $4$ & $1$ & $2$ & $3$ & $4$ & $4$ & $4$ & $4$ & $4$ & $4$ & $4$ & $4$ & $4$ & $4$ & $4$ & $4$ & $4$ & $4$ & $4$ & $4$ & $4$ & $4$ & $4$ & $4$ & $4$ & $4$ & $4$ & $4$ & $4$ & $4$ & $4$ & $4$ & $4$\\
        \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}%
}
\makeatletter
\ifdim\wd\mt>\textwidth
\setlength\@tempdima   {\paperheight}%
\setlength\paperheight {\paperwidth}%
\setlength\paperwidth  {\@tempdima}%
\setlength\pdfpageheight{\paperheight}%
\setlength\pdfpagewidth{\paperwidth}%
\setlength{\textwidth}{\paperwidth}%
\addtolength{\textwidth}{-2\oddsidemargin}%
\addtolength{\textwidth}{-2\hoffset}%
\addtolength{\textwidth}{-2in}%
\setlength{\hsize}{\textwidth}%
\fi
\makeatother
\begin{table}[htp]\setlength{\hsize}{\textwidth}%
\centering
\usebox\mt
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sadly, as soon as the page gets flipped due to the size of the table, the centering no longer seems to work (even if the table is slightly smaller than the space it could take up in landscape orientation). Any idea what I can do about that?

Comment: what do you mean? (table is not centered or caption)

Comment: please try to compile these two options: [portrait](https://bpaste.net/show/4b4bc38690b4) and [landscape](https://bpaste.net/show/880b81638ce9). You will notice that the second one is no longer centered. Any ideas what I could do?

Comment: @TheChymera answer updated.

Comment: thank you so much for your update - sadly, this does no appear to influence the issue at all. Is, e.g. [this code](https://bpaste.net/show/dd5f8e2d5af0) compiling to a centered table on your end?

Comment: @TheChymera when I past only your `tabular` to my answer it's centered. Why? in my answer i noted that one should remember to edit `\addtolength{\textwidth}{-3cm}` here 3cm is left + right (margins). In your last code you don't use `geometry` at all and margins are differents. To make this automatic you need a more adaptation, I will try (I already answer a similar question here). This can be easy if you use Koma-script class.

Comment: Sorry, i was unaware of my omission. I will try this again in a few hours. If it was really just that than the issue is solved :)

Comment: @TheChymera the answer was edited.